# csv writing alternate whitespace in lines within a loop python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a code for generating a csv file shown below.

```
import csv

csvData = [["HAI", "Hello"]]
while(1):
    with open('test.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerows(csvData)
    csvFile.close()
```

When i run this code it will generate a csv file like this

1."HAI","Hello"

3."HAI","Hello"

That is it will generate on alternative lines,that is first write takes palce on line 1 ,second write takes on line 3.I want to write it on line 2. Anybody please help me.

Comment: You can try using the approach specified in my answer below. I tested it with your minimal working example, and it produced the correct output for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for CSV formatting parameters](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params), you will see that there is the argument `lineterminator`, which defaults to `\r\n`.

You can get your desired output by simply passing a regular `\n` like so:

```
writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator="\n")
```